# Error in the initialisation of initial layer of Keras Tuner

Tags: keras-tuner

I'm getting the value error of incompatible shape of tensors of my code. The following is my code :

---

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import ReLU,LeakyReLU,ELU,PReLU,Softmax
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers.legacy import SGD,Adam
from keras_tuner.tuners import RandomSearch
from tensorflow.keras.initializers import he_normal
import random
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score,classification_report,confusion_matrix
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

seed_value = 42
np.random.seed(seed_value)
random.seed(seed_value)
tf.random.set_seed(seed_value)


df=pd.read_csv('IRIS.csv')

df['species']=df['species'].replace({
    'Iris-setosa':0,
    'Iris-versicolor':1,
    'Iris-virginica':2})
    

x=df.drop(columns=['species'],axis=1)
y=df['species']

xtrain,xtest,ytrain,ytest=train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.3,random_state=42)

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc=StandardScaler()
xtrain_scaled=sc.fit_transform(xtrain)
xtest_scaled=sc.transform(xtest)

ytrain_encoded = to_categorical(ytrain,3)
ytest_encoded=to_categorical(ytest,3)

def build_model(hp):
    model=Sequential()
    units=hp.Int('units',min_value=18,max_value=729,step=9)
    bias_initiliazer=he_normal(seed=None)
    
    model.add(Dense(units=hp.Int('initial neurons for first layer',min_value=9,max_value=729,step=9,default=9),
                    kernel_initializer='he_normal',
                    use_bias=True,
                    bias_initializer=bias_initiliazer,
                    activation='relu',
                    input_dim=4))
    
    
    
    
    counter=0
    for i in range(hp.Int('num_layers',min_value=2,max_value=20,step=1)):
        if counter==0:

            model.add(Dense(units=units,
                            kernel_initializer='he_normal',
                            use_bias=True,
                            bias_initializer=bias_initiliazer,
                            activation='relu'),)
            model.add(Dropout(hp.Choice('dropout',values=[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9])))
        else:
                model.add(Dense(units=units,
                                kernel_initializer='he_normal',
                                use_bias=True,
                                bias_initializer=bias_initiliazer,
                                activation='relu'))
                model.add(Dropout(hp.Choice('dropout',values=[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9])))
                counter+=1
    model.add(Dense(3,activation='softmax'))
    learning_rate = hp.Float("lr", min_value=1e-4, max_value=1e-2, sampling="log")
    model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate),
                  loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy']
                  )
    return model

tuner=RandomSearch(
    hypermodel=build_model,
    objective='val_accuracy',
    max_trials=5,
    seed=42,
    executions_per_trial=5)
tuner.search(xtrain_scaled,ytrain_encoded,
             epochs=5,
             validation_data=(xtest_scaled,ytest_encoded))
main_model=tuner.get_best_models(num_models=1)[0]
model_history=main_model.fit(xtrain_scaled,ytrain_encoded,epochs=100,initial_epoch=11,batch_size=32,
          validation_data=(xtest_scaled,ytest_encoded),
          
          validation_split=0.33)
ypred_test=np.argmax(main_model.predict(xtest_scaled),axis=-1)
ypred_train=np.argmax(main_model.predict(xtrain_scaled),axis=-1)
missclassified=np.sum(ytest != ypred_test)
classified=np.sum(ytest== ypred_test)
print('Count of missclassified samples are: ',missclassified)
print('Count of classified samples are: ',classified)
print('Classification report for training set as follows:\n',classification_report(ytrain,ypred_train))
print('-'*50)
print('Classification report for testing set as follows:\n',classification_report(ytest,ypred_test))
print('Training set accuracy is {:.2f}'.format(accuracy_score(ytrain,ypred_train)))
print('Training set accuracy is {:.2f}'.format(accuracy_score(ytest,ypred_test)))
print('Confusion matrix: {}\n'.format(confusion_matrix(ytest,ypred_test)))
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(5, 5))

# Plot Accuracy
axs[0].plot(model_history.history['accuracy'])
axs[0].plot(model_history.history['val_accuracy'])
axs[0].set_title("Accuracy")
axs[0].legend(['train', 'test'])

# Plot Loss
axs[1].plot(model_history.history['loss'])
axs[1].plot(model_history.history['val_loss'])
axs[1].set_title('Loss')
axs[1].legend(['Train', 'Test'])

# Display the subplots
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

---

```
The error as follows:

ValueError: Received incompatible tensor with shape (512,) when attempting to restore variable with shape (9,) and name dense/bias:0.
WARNING:tensorflow:Detecting that an object or model or tf.train.Checkpoint is being deleted with unrestored values. See the following logs for the specific values in question. To silence these warnings, use `status.expect_partial()`. See https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Checkpoint#restorefor details about the status object returned by the restore function.
```

---

But one things is strange that the above code is runnign perfectly well in **GOOGLE COLAB** Notebooks. But its not running in the local machine like Visual Studio Code. The following are the versions which Im using for the above code:

Tensorflow:-  2.12.0

Keras Tuner:- 1.3.5

Hoping that anyone can give the reply as soon as possible.

Regrads

Guna Sekhar.